# помогите разобраться с работой while

Tags: php, while

Объясните плиз назначение цикла while в коде функции, понимаю что тут идет проверка на конец файла но почему в цикле ни чего не делается? не легче было сделать проверку по if? 
 зараннее спасибо

```
function whois($domain)
{
  echo $domain;
  $whoisdom='whois.nic.ru';
  //
  $ask=fsockopen($whoisdom, 43, $errno, $errstr, 30);
  if(!isset($ask)) 
  {
    $respons = "$errstr ($errno)";
  }
  else
  {
    $respons="";
    fputs($ask, "$domain\r\n");
    while(!feof($ask))
    $respons .=fread($ask, 1500);
    fclose($ask);
  }
  //$respons=str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $respons);
  return $respons;
}
$a=whois("vk.com");
echo $a;
```

Comment: Пока файл не закончен читай и листай дальше. Думаю что так понятно) Работай пока не конец.

Answer (score 1):

Тело цикла — строка `$respons .=fread($ask, 1500);`

В цикле читается до конца в переменную `$respons` вывод `whois` по заданному имени домена.

Comment: точно после вайла же ; нет!!!!! спасибо большое просмотрел